# Retrieving JSON from java class using Struts2

Tags: java, jquery, json, struts2

I am having problems in retrieving Json data through struts2. Below is my code :
**struts.xml**

```
  <struts>

    <package name="default"  extends="struts-default,json-default">
    <action name="getMenuInfo" class="test.AppTaskConfigDAOImpl" method="getJsonData">
    <result type="json">
    <param name="root">jsonResponse</param>
    </result>
    </action>
    </package>

    </struts>
```

Java Class:

```
public String getJsonData() {
 {
        List<AppTaskConfig> records = null;
        String jsonResponse;
    try {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory= new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(AppTaskConfig.class);
        records = (List<AppTaskConfig>)criteria.list();

        ClassMetadata classMetadata = sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(AppTaskConfig.class); 
        String [] names=classMetadata.getPropertyNames();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        ConvertToJson jsondoc= new ConvertToJson();

        jsonResponse=jsondoc.toJsonArray(records, names[2]).toString();
        System.out.println(jsonResponse);

    } 
    catch (HibernateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
}
```

**JavaScript code :**
I am fetching jsonResponse variable and using it in Jquery.

```
$.getJSON('getMenuInfo.action', function(json) {

        $.each(json, function (key, value) {
            alert(value);
        });

                                            });
```

No alert message is showing . I am showing alerts on HTML page.I am trying to debug but its not even going into java method .Please let me know the correct way to proceed.
Help is appreciated!

Comment: Portal environment? Don't you think it is relevant information? Anyway try to use `<s:url>` tag.

Comment: Is the action even called ? If yes, then what response do you receive ? (you can check in th developer tools or directly hit the url in a browser)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the Getter for your root object `String jsonResponse;`

AND your root object must be a Class variable, not a Method variable.

Comment: Looking at the code provided `jsonResponse` is method variable. :)

Comment: The strange indentation and the missing class name fooled me :)